# Non-trivial homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x^n-1 \rangle$ to $\mathbb{Z}_m[x]/\langle x^n+1 \rangle$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, quotient-spaces, ring-homomorphism

Is there any non-trivial homomorphism from $R_1=\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x^n-1 \rangle$ to $R_2=\mathbb{Z}_m[x]/\langle x^n+1 \rangle$, for all $m>1$ (no necessarily prime)? (Note that the elements in $R_1$ can have negative values, while the ones in $R_2$ only non-negatives).

As there is a finite number of elements in $R_2$ and an infinite (countable) number of elements in $R_1$, I know that there could not be any isomorphism. But is there a way to construct a homomorphism?

Comment: If $n$ is odd, consider $x\mapsto -x$.

Comment: The homomorphism should be from $R_1$ to $R_2$.

Comment: @liwuen What Angina said is from $R_1$ to $R_2$. More generally, you could even just send $x$ to $1$.